# Kendo Ui Window textbox foxus

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have a kendo window with a text box in it. On activation, the focus should be set to the textbox. the below code does that.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    if (!$("#SearchDialog").data("kendoWindow")) {
        $("#SearchDialog").kendoWindow({
            visible: false,

            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            activate: function () {
                $("#GlobalSearch").select();
            }

        });
    }  
});
```

however when I apply some css in the `open()` function, the texbox does not get focus.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!$("#SearchDialog").data("kendoWindow")) {
        $("#SearchDialog").kendoWindow({
            visible: false,

            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            activate: function () {
                $("#GlobalSearch").select();
            },
            open: function() {
                this.wrapper.css({ top: 100, width: 500, display: 'block', marginLeft: '-265px', left: '50%' });                 
            }            
        });
    }
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3uwhue/1/) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when calling `this.wrapper.css` *Activate* event is not triggered. The best approach to set window attributes with [position](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-position) and [width](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-width)